# Errors trying to solve Boundary Value Problem, using NDSolve and Shooting method

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a differential equation with two differential boundary values(`x'[t]=0, x'[t]=1`), using NDSolve and the Shooting method, but the code does not work, giving me errors, and I could not figure out what the problem might be?!

````
Clearall["Global`*"];
g = 10;
r = 0.002;
den = 1000;
ten = 0.072;


sols = Map[
   First[NDSolve[{x[
          t] - ((ten/g*
             den) (x'[t] + (x'[t])^3 + 
              t*x''[t])/(t (1 + x'[t])^1.5)) == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
       x'[r] == 1}, x, t, 
      Method -> {"Shooting", 
        "StartingInitialConditions" -> {x[0] == #, x'[0] == 0}}]] &,
   {1, 4, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. sols], {t, 0, 0.002}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue, Green}]


```
````

Comment: Your differential equation is singular at $t=0$. To illustrate, if you replace `t*x''[t]` by `(t+eps)*x''[t]` and also replace the factor `t` in the denominator by `t+eps`, for say `eps = 10^(-6)`, then your code runs without error.

Comment: Thank you very much